# Im learning c++, file handling. i came across a piece of code that i did not understand

Tags: c++

What is the use of `cin.get(ch);` in the following code? Why and when should I use it and what is the problem if I don't use it.

This code is from c++ sumit arora computer science with C++ textbook. I am using Code Blocks for my C++ code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream fil;
    char name[80],ch;
    int age;
    fil.open("mytext.txt",ios::out);
    for(int i = 0;i < 5;++i)
    {
        cout<<"Enter your name";
        cin.get(name,80);
        cout<<"Enter your age";
        cin>>age;
        cin.get(ch);        // What is the purpose of this line?
        fil<<name<<"\n"<<age<<"\n";
    }
    fil.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your book should not be encouraging you to be using arrays of char - you should be using std::string. Also this `#include<fstream.h>` indicates the book is wildly obsolete.

Comment: Hi,got that its better to use strings instead of array char.What's wrong with fstream.h?

Comment: I think its just beginner level stuff thats why it seems 'obsolete' to you,if im wrong correct me

Comment: You are wrong - there is no such thing as `fstream.h` in modern C++.

Comment: Oh Okay.im just learning basics. I've seen people use it though

Comment: `fatal error: fstream.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay so whats better

Comment: `#include <fstream>`, like you did with `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the reference for [`std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). It's a weird way of ignoring the next character, which is most likely the line break after the inputted number. `cin.get(ch)` extracts the next character and puts it into `ch`, which is never used. It would make more sense to use `cin.ignore()` instead of extracting into a dummy variable.

Comment: If I run the program without it then it doesn't execute properly

Comment: @AryanParekh Sorry, I forgot that the first read is done using `cin.get`, which doesn't skip leading whitespace, instead of the `>>` operator.